# MySQL Joins Returning Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, join, left-join

I have a `MySQL` statement that I am using to query a table of contacts. When they are loaded into my `DataGrid` however there are multiple copies of the same contact (there is only 1 in the table).

This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my `MySQL` statement. This is what I have so far;

```
myQuery.CommandText = @"SELECT contacts.contactID, contacts.companyID, 
companies.name, contacts.donestatus, employees.name,
people.ID, people.firstname, people.lastname, 
contacts.contractID, contacts.date, contacts.time, 
presets.presettext, contacts.madeby, contacts.description
FROM contacts
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON contacts.companyID = companies.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees ON contacts.employeeID = employees.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON contacts.personID = people.ID
JOIN presets ON contacts.type = presets.presetIDFoxPro
WHERE contacts.companyid = @CompanyID
AND presets.presetreferencefoxpro = 8
ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";
```

I have checked the method and it is definitely only called once, so to me it must be the statement. Are the multiple `JOINS` resulting in a `Contact` being loaded for every `JOIN` that is successful?

Comment: When doing this join and - for example - the contact is associated with two companies, you'll get 2 rows back with the same contact, one for each company.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I thought this was going to be the case. Do I need to use a different type of join?

Comment: could you run this query in database side? I think you will get your answer there.

Comment: @Ajay2707 I retrieve multiple rows for each query so it is definitely the query. How can I exclude replicas? Should I use `DISTINCT`? Is that a temporary fix?

Comment: you just execute with hard cord company-id in db side. for multiple rows for each query, you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation it depends what you want to appear. If a contact can have multiple related companies, employees or people then you will bring back a record with every combination of them with your current SQL. For example if a contact had 2 of each then 8 rows (ie, 2 x 2 x 2) would come back for that contact.

If you want all the details on one line for each contact then you can use sub queries to get all the details concatenated for each contact, and then join the results of that against the contact table.

For a simple example:-

```
SELECT contacts.contactID, contacts.companyID, 
        sub_companies.name, contacts.donestatus, sub_employees.name,
        sub_people.all_id, sub_people.all_firstname, sub_people.all_lastname, 
        contacts.contractID, contacts.date, contacts.time, 
        presets.presettext, contacts.madeby, contacts.description
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN presets ON contacts.type = presets.presetIDFoxPro
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
    FROM companies 
    GROUP BY ID
) sub_companies ON contacts.companyID = sub_companies.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY ID
) sub_employees ON contacts.employeeID = sub_employees.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS all_id, GROUP_CONCAT(firstname) AS all_firstname, GROUP_CONCAT(lastname) AS all_lastname
    FROM people 
    GROUP BY ID
) sub_people ON contacts.personID = sub_people.ID
WHERE contacts.companyid = @CompanyID
AND presets.presetreferencefoxpro = 8
ORDER BY contacts.date DESC
```